# Чем можно воспроизвести файл с расширением .unity3d?

Tags: unity3d

Помогите, мне необходимо открыть ролик из игры, но формат ролика .unity3d чем можно его открыть?

Comment: Может быть Unity3D?

Comment: Пробывал, не открывает

Comment: Раньше для открытия данного файла использовался Unity Flas Player, но сейчас то его уже нет, а файл открыть надо)

Comment: вы бы расшифровали (прямо в тексте вопроса), что именно подразумеваете под словом «открыть». потому что если это, например, «просмотреть содержимое данного файла», то любой текстовый редактор вам покажет это содержимое.

Comment: Исправил, мне необходимо просмотреть данный видеоролик

Comment: А что значит "Его уже нет", на просторах негде скачать?